# Pass PaintEventArgs into method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following method in C#:

```
private string adjustColumnValueLength(String value, int maxLength, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Set up our string font
    System.Drawing.Font printFontText = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);            
    SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
    string newValue = value;

    // Loop until the string fits the size we need
    for (int x = value.Length; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        // Measure the string
        newValue = value.Substring(0, x);
        stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(newValue, printFontText);
        Size roundedSize = Size.Round(stringSize);
        if (Int32.Parse(roundedSize.ToString()) <= maxLength)
        {
            return newValue;
        }
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

I am calling this from within another method to get the length of a string to match the width in pixels I have to display it, however I have NO idea how I am supposed to pass in the `PaintEventArgs`.  I've tried using `System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs` but that does not work.

How can this be accomplished?

**UPDATE**

```
private void btnPrintTicket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Loop over items in the listScanData object and create a ticket for printing showing
        // the Job #, In/Out, Part #, Name, Description and Qty
        line = 0;
        page = 1;
        xCoord = 50;
        yCoord = 180;
        printTicket = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
        printTicket.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(this.ticketData);
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.Document = printTicket;
        DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printTicket.Print();
        }
    }

    private void ticketData(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // Insert code here to render the content we want to print
        System.Drawing.Font printFontHeading = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 18, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
        System.Drawing.Font printFontSubheading = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
        System.Drawing.Font printFontFooter = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic);
        System.Drawing.Font printFontLabels = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline);
        System.Drawing.Font printFontText = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

        // Draw our heading and subheading
        string printHeader = "Header 1";            
        string printSubHeader = "Subheader";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(printHeader, printFontHeading, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 50, 50);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(printSubHeader, printFontSubheading, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 50, 80);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(50, 110), new Point(800, 110));            

        // Draw our table headers
        string thType = "Type:"; string thName = "Name:"; string thNo = "No:"; string thQty = "Qty:"; string thBackorderQty = "Backorder Qty:";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(thType, printFontLabels, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 50, 150);            
        e.Graphics.DrawString(thName, printFontLabels, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 200, 150);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(thNo, printFontLabels, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 400, 150);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(thQty, printFontLabels, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 550, 150);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(thBackorderQty, printFontLabels, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 650, 150);

        int counter = 0;

        // Loop over our data to print it - incrementing our yCoord var by 30 each iteration (so the text doesn't overlap)
        for (; line < myGlobals.summaryData.Count; line++ )
        {
            // If our line var is greater than the data count, we have no more pages to print
            if (counter > 26)
            {
                // Draw our footer on the page
                xCoord = 350;
                yCoord = 1010;                    
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Page " + page, printFontFooter, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, xCoord, yCoord);
                page++;

                // Reset our counter and our x/y coord
                counter = 0;
                xCoord = 50;
                yCoord = 180;                    

                // Indicate we have more to print and return
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;    
            }

            // Assign local vars with the data we need for this iteration
            string tdScanType = myGlobals.summaryData[line].ScanType.ToString();
            string tdScanName = myGlobals.getProductName(myGlobals.summaryData[line].Barcode.ToString());
            //if (tdScanName.Length > 25) { tdScanName = tdScanName.Substring(0, 25); }
            tdScanName = adjustColumnValueLength(tdScanName, 200);
            string tdScanPartNo = myGlobals.getProductNumber(myGlobals.summaryData[line].Barcode.ToString());
            //if (tdScanPartNo.Length > 15) { tdScanPartNo = tdScanPartNo.Substring(0, 15); }
            tdScanPartNo = adjustColumnValueLength(tdScanPartNo, 150);
            string tdScanQty = myGlobals.summaryData[line].Qty.ToString();
            string tdScanBackorderQty = myGlobals.summaryData[line].BackorderQty.ToString();

            // Draw the scan type
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tdScanType, printFontText, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, xCoord, yCoord);

            // Increment our xCoord
            xCoord += 150;

            // Draw the scan name
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tdScanName, printFontText, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, xCoord, yCoord);

            // Increment our xCoord
            xCoord += 200;

            // Draw the scan part no
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tdScanPartNo, printFontText, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, xCoord, yCoord);                

            // Increment our xCoord
            xCoord += 150;

            // Draw the scan qty
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tdScanQty, printFontText, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, xCoord, yCoord);

            // Increment our xCoord
            xCoord += 100;

            // Draw the scan backorder qty
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tdScanBackorderQty, printFontText, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, xCoord, yCoord);

            // Reset our xCoord and increment our yCoord
            xCoord = 50;
            yCoord += 30;               

            // Increment our counter
            counter++;
        }

        // Draw our footer on the page
        xCoord = 350;
        yCoord = 1010;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Page " + page, printFontFooter, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, xCoord, yCoord);
        e.HasMorePages = false;            
    }

    private string adjustColumnValueLength(String value, int maxLength)
    {
        // Set up our string font
        System.Drawing.Font printFontText = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
        string newValue = value;

        // Loop until the string fits the size we need
        for (int x = value.Length; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            // Measure the string
            newValue = value.Substring(0, x);
            //stringSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(newValue, printFontText);                
            stringSize = g.MeasureString(newValue, printFontText);
            Size roundedSize = Size.Round(stringSize);
            if (Int32.Parse(roundedSize.ToString()) <= maxLength)
            {
                return newValue;
            }
        }
        return newValue;
    }
```

Complete code provided above, I'm trying to call the adjustColumnValueLength from within the ticketData method so that I can substring the value that is being printed to only the width I have available for that column.

Comment: You don't need `e`, just `e.Graphics`. Find out what Type it is and how you make one.

Comment: Clarify how/where/why you call this.

Comment: After the edit: You have 2 different `e`s, but the `e.Graphic`s are compatible.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the btnPrintTicket_Click method above is called when a user clicks the "Print Ticket" button from the application.  Which then fires off the printing methods below

Comment: This is a Windows FORMS application fyi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only call that method from a `Paint` event handler. I guess you have something in your code like:

```
private void Control_Paint(object sender, PainEventArgs e) { ... }
```

You should call your method from there (and nowhere else!):

```
private void Control_Paint(object sender, PainEventArgs e)
{
    adjustColumnValueLength("value", 10, e);
}
```

If you don't have that, create a event handler:

```
this.Control.Paint += Control_Paint;
```

Also read: [Custom Control Painting and Rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kxys6ytf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm trying to call this from within a method that has a constructor that looks like this private void ticketData(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)

Comment: Then just pass in `PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics` into the method instead of the `PaintEventArgs`.

Comment: He should __not__ call this from a Paint event handler or from OnPaint.

Comment: @PatrickHofman could you provide example?  I'm trying to call method like so myString = adjustColumnValueLength(myString, 150, e) where e is equal to the System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs that is defined in the methods constructor where I am calling the adjustcolumnValueLength method.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Imo calling methods from the Paint event passing out the e parameter or just the Graphics object is just fine and a good and natural way to break down the code into smaller pieces.

Comment: @TaW: That's my opinion too. Thanks.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to have an EventArgs handy, the method name suggests something related to Layout (ie in Form_Load). Moving that to a Paint event is a very bad idea. But the OP should clarify.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - please see update above.  I'm trying to take a string and substring it down to a specific length in pixels so that it fits where it is being drawn without overlapping into the next column

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I agree, and that is in my post. That doesn't mean he can't pass the graphics from the event handler to another method.